# Gnome Shell theme displays orange title bars

Tags: 11.10, gnome, themes

I've upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 beta and installed Gnome Shell and logged on with the Gnome Shell session. My window title bars are orange like this: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/M55j9.png]

Any way to fix?

Comment: Change the theme.

Comment: Tried, even used Gnome Tweak Tool, nothing brings normal window borders back.

Comment: When i tried to sue the Ambience window borders in GNome Shell this happened, changing them  to Adwaita solved it, i'm not sure why Ambience is now a GTK 3 theme too.

Comment: :( Tried that too, still the window title bar won't change from this classic like theme...

Comment: Its called beta for a reason. Simply try again when it's officially released

Comment: Or, better yet, a [bug should probably be filed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so this will (hopefully) be fixed once it's officially released. (I've run into this problem too, btw, but before I could report it my virtual machine blew up.)

Comment: A bug was already filed as http://pad.lv/800315

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install `gnome-tweak-tool` and `gnome-themes-standard`, then use `gnome-tweak-tool` to change your window border theme to something supported by mutter (such as Adwaita).

If it does not apply immediately, log on and log back in. Also ensure you've installed all the updates.

Comment: Thanks! The log out and in worked after applying Adwaita. Would like to see Ambiance supported - I find this Adwaita theme too bright.

Comment: @nLinked it is a known issue and it's being worked on. BTW if this answered your question, you can mark it as answered.

Comment: @nLinked: you're welcome :)